# ftdi_usb_open() returns -8 on Linux, but the same code is working on Mac

Tags: linux, ftdi

I am using FT2232H in SYNC FIFO FT245 mode and I can't get it working on Linux, my code is perfectly working on Mac OS X, but it doesn't on Linux.

I have installed both libftdi1 and libftdi-dev packages.

Relevant parts of code:

```cpp
    #define PID 0x6010

    .
    .
    .

    if(vftdic == NULL)
    {
        this->ftdic = static_cast<struct ftdi_context*>(malloc(sizeof(struct ftdi_context)));
    }
    else
    {
        this->ftdic = vftdic;
    }
    int f;
    // Init 1. channel
    if (ftdi_init(ftdic) < 0)
    {
        throw DeviceException("ftdi_init failure\n", FTDI_ERROR);
    }
    ftdi_set_interface(ftdic, INTERFACE_A);
    f = ftdi_usb_open(ftdic, 0x0403, PID);
    if (f < 0 && (f != -5))
    {
        //here f is equal to -8 only on Linux
        throw DeviceException("Unable to open FTDI device, channel A\n", FTDI_ERROR);
    }
```

Here is listing from lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C Dual USB-UART/FIFO IC
```

All hardware used is the same (MacBook Pro 2010 + my usb device with ft2232h).

Comment: 1) Do you have permission to the device node?  Linux systems usually use a udev rule to make recognized USB devices available to ordinary users; OSX seems to grant it by default.  2) Is it perhaps already claimed by a USB-serial driver which you would need to detach?  Linux tends to have these as part of the distribution, on OSX they would have to be specifically installed, ie, less likely to be accidentally interfering.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I have rmmod-ed ftdi_sio from kernel (reason 2) and runned my app as root (and also reason 1), how could I make these actions automatic and presumably not a asking for root permissions, especially rmmoding of ftdi_sio? I know that there is some udev blacklist, but I would like it to make it more generic that any user of my device will not have to blacklist some modules..

Comment: The first-class approach is to use a custom VID/PID which will not be recognized as a USB serial device by the typical linux driver.  But you'll need to provide instructions or a script for the udev rule to grant permission anyway, so you can consider doing this for the ignore quirk on USB serial as well.

Comment: There's also an ability in something like libusb to try to reclaim a desired device from a stock driver - don't know if that would apply to your ftdi library or not.

Comment: Thank you :), I'll probably change PID in EEPROM as it's simplest solution, though I'll still have to fix permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to making sure you have permission to the device node, you must verify that no other driver (such as a USB serial driver which normally ships with a linux distribution) has claimed the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Does the user account you're using have permissions to access the raw USB bus? Check permissions of the device file corresponding to your FTDI located somewhere below `/dev/bus/usb` – most like you don't have permissions to access it.

In that case add some UDev rules to place the device file in the ownership of some dedicated group and and add yourself to the members of this group.

Comment: Oh permissions, I missed that one .. thought that USB devices are not that constrained. Been long time since I was last using linux day-to-day :)

Comment: Did quick and dirty check if it is in fact permission problem and have ran my program as root but it's all the same.. Error code -8.